# Identifying port on which a serice is ruuning from within that service itself

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I am writing a WCF service to handle multipart batch requests. Once I get a multipart request which inturn consists of multiple GET requests, I have to execute all those GET request on the localhost. I am able to do so using the HttpClient using the hostname of the machine, but in order to optimize things, I want to skip the DNS lookup. The problem now I facing is how to figure out that on which port my serive is running?

Comment: If you started the service didn't you need to open the port? Or I'm I missing something?

Comment: If the code is other code within the same service, you shouldn't be thinking about hitting the network stack again - just directly call the appropriate method. If it's not within the same service, how is the port that your service is on relevant?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I can call the method directly, but what about the response headers, how am I going to get that? As a part of multipart response, I have to return the headers of individual response as well.

Comment: Providing your code or pseudo code might help explain the issue better.