# Accessing a hosted service from within that service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have a WCF service hosted in Azure environment. I am trying to add support for batch request in it. Now, I am getting a set of GET requests batched as single POST requests. On receiving a batch request, I have to fire individual GET requests, get the response including headers and return the combined response.

Currently, on getting a batch request, I extract out individula GET requests and fire them individually using `HttpClient` with host as the public hostname of the service. Now, I am thinking that since my control is already inside the service I want to access, then why to go through the whole DNS system. Whyn't just call the service using `localhost`. But I am not getting that what port should I use to access my service.

Also, are there any standard way of doing such thing in WCF service and Azure?

PS: I am new to this whole Azure/IIS/Web Service world.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Identifying port on which a serice is ruuning from within that service itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545919/identifying-port-on-which-a-serice-is-ruuning-from-within-that-service-itself)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the batch data in the service, then simply call the single method (not via HTTP) as a regular method call in side your service:

```
public void SomeBatchRequest(List<Somedata> data) {
    foreach (var d in data) {
        ProcessSingle(d);
    }
}

public void ProcessSingle(Somedata d) {
    // do something with d
    ....
}
```